# Generating C++ header file android

Tags: java, android, c++

I have been trying to create a `C++ header` file for 3 days now, I downloaded a project on Github that uses `C++`, the issue is I want to modify the project as it only runs on `armeabi-v7a` architecture. I want to generate `.so` files for both `armeabi-v7a` and `x86`, below is the java class:

```
package me.myname.scanner.scanlibrary
/**
* Created by jhansi on 28/03/15.
 */

public class ScanActivity extends Activity implements IScanner {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.scan_layout);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    PickImageFragment fragment = new PickImageFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(ScanConstants.OPEN_INTENT_PREFERENCE, getPreferenceContent());
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

protected int getPreferenceContent() {
    return getIntent().getIntExtra(ScanConstants.OPEN_INTENT_PREFERENCE, 0);
}

@Override
public void onBitmapSelect(Uri uri) {
    ScanFragment fragment = new ScanFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(ScanConstants.SELECTED_BITMAP, uri);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(ScanFragment.class.toString());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void onScanFinish(Uri uri) {
    ResultFragment fragment = new ResultFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(ScanConstants.SCANNED_RESULT, uri);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(ResultFragment.class.toString());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

public native Bitmap getScannedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3, float x4, float y4);

public native Bitmap getGrayBitmap(Bitmap bitmap);

public native Bitmap getMagicColorBitmap(Bitmap bitmap);

public native Bitmap getBWBitmap(Bitmap bitmap);

public native float[] getPoints(Bitmap bitmap);

static {
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java");
    System.loadLibrary("Scanner");
}
```

The Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
//point of mofication
APP_ABI := x86 armeabi
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
include sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := Scanner
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := scan.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lm -llog -landroid
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -ljnigraphics
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI :=  x86 armeabi
APP_PLATFORM := android-14
```

Top level gradle.build

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "me.myname.scanner"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled false
    ndk
            {
                moduleName "Scanner"
            }
}


sourceSets.main
        {
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
        }


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
```

}

gradle.properties

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your 
  build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -  XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
#   

 http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/
 multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true

android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

But even after all this I cannot generate both the `Header` file and `.so`, my project structure is as shown in the image

[image: Project Structure]

This is my first time dealing with `JNI`, I have read and watched a bunch of videos, its not working for me. All help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sooooo, what you're saying is you would like help to either a) translate this Java code to C++ or b) cross compile it?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the reason why my code was not generating any `header` or `.so` files, firstly it seems sometimes `ndk` can be a bit off, like mine, it was simply not working, no errors nothing. I managed to generate the header files manually, I navigated to my `java` directory through `cmd` as `admin` to avoid any errors that might need administrative rights then entered the command `javah -d jni -classpath c/path/to/android/sdk/compileplatform/android.jar; c/path/to/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug -force com.package.containing.my.class.andtheclassitself`
this generated the header file, then I went on and navigated to the `ndk` root directory and entered the command `ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=c/path/to/my/app/src/main APP_BUID_SCRIPT=c/path/to/my/project/Android.mk` this compiled my `.so` files.

Comment: Please mark this as solved by yourself, @Chrometobia